# Eigenvalues of $A + \lambda I $

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is an $n \times n $ matrix and $\lambda \geq 0$

> > What can we say about the eignevalues of ($A+ \lambda I$)

Comment: See, I need to modify a matrix into a positive definite matrix for some optimization scheme.In fact I require minimum  $\lambda$ that makes it positive definite.

Comment: @user107723 Keep in mind that this modification would only result in a positive definite matrix if you start with a Hermitian (i.e. symmetric) matrix.

Comment: Yes, I missed it. A is a symmetric matrix. Can you enlighten about it why is it so ?

Comment: @user107723 you mean why $A$ would have to be symmetric?  Remember that a matrix $M$ is positive semidefinite if and only if all its eigenvalues are positive **and** $M$ is symmetric.  Note that $A + \lambda I$ can only be symmetric if $A$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We can define the eigenvalues of a matrix $M$ to be the values $\mu$ for which $M - \mu I$ is singular (i.e. has a determinant of zero).

Answer (score 1):

Take an eigenvalue $\mu$ of the matrix $A$. Therefore, you have a vector $v$ such that $Av = \mu v$.

Take a look at what multiplying $A+\lambda I$ with $v$ does.

Answer (score 1):

If $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $x$ is an eigenvector associated to $\mu$ then
$$(A+\lambda I)x=(\mu+\lambda)x$$
hence we see that
$$\operatorname{sp}(A+\lambda I)=\operatorname{sp}(A)+\lambda=\{\mu+\lambda,\quad\mu\in\operatorname{sp}(A)\}$$